# Azure AD sync shows success but no new users in portal

Tags: azure, active-directory

I installed Azure AD Connect and ran an initial full sync with filter to just cover a test OU of 20 users.  The synchronization tool shows success but when I go to the portal I see a sync status is enabled, but there is a message "last sync: sync has never run".  Federated domains is also 0.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot fixed it.  I think that forced it to follow the scheduler.  I'm not sure why my manual syncs didn't work